# self join with sum field

Tags: mysql, join

I have data like this
table t_prod

```
+---------+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|t_prod_id|t_prod_lot|t_prod_sublot|t_prod_card|t_prod_qty|
+---------+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|    4    |   R001   |      1      |      1    |   6000   |
|    5    |   R001   |      1      |      2    |   6000   |
|    6    |   R001   |      1      |      3    |   6000   |
|    10   |   R001   |      1      |      4    |   6000   |
|    11   |   R001   |      1      |      5    |   6000   |
|    12   |   R001   |      1      |      6    |   6000   |
|    13   |   R001   |      2      |      1    |   6000   |
|    34   |   R001   |      2      |      2    |   6000   |
|    36   |   R001   |      2      |      3    |   2000   |
+---------+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

and i want result like this when i select t_prod_lot = R001. count t_prod_sublot when same value and sum t_prod_qty when t_prod_sublot same value

```
+---------+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+--------------------+---------------+
|t_prod_id|t_prod_lot|t_prod_sublot|t_prod_card|t_prod_qty|count(t_prod_sublot)|sum(t_prod_qty)|
+---------+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+--------------------+---------------+
|    4    |   R001   |      1      |      1    |   6000   |          6         |      36000    |
|    5    |   R001   |      1      |      2    |   6000   |          6         |      36000    |
|    6    |   R001   |      1      |      3    |   6000   |          6         |      36000    |  
|    10   |   R001   |      1      |      4    |   6000   |          6         |      36000    |  
|    11   |   R001   |      1      |      5    |   6000   |          6         |      36000    |  
|    12   |   R001   |      1      |      6    |   6000   |          6         |      36000    |  
|    13   |   R001   |      2      |      1    |   6000   |          3         |      14000    |  
|    34   |   R001   |      2      |      2    |   6000   |          3         |      14000    |  
|    36   |   R001   |      2      |      3    |   2000   |          3         |      14000    |  
+---------+----------+-------------+-----------+----------+--------------------+---------------+
```

what is the query to produce this result ?
[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9189e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option using a `join` with a subquery to `count` and `sum` the values:

```
select *
from t_prod t join (
  select t_prod_lot, t_prod_sublot, 
        count(t_prod_card) t_prod_card_cnt, 
        sum(t_prod_qty) t_prod_qty_sum
  from t_prod
  group by t_prod_lot, t_prod_sublot
) t2 on t.t_prod_lot = t2.t_prod_lot and t.t_prod_sublot = t2.t_prod_sublot
```

- [Updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c860f2/1)